# IOS : message doesn't appear immediately in tableview from firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

when i add first message it's appear immediately in the tableview but next messages don't appear i have to back and return to the same chat to get them

[retrieve messages method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw0qV.png)

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4SqY.png)

[viewDidLoad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5BlA.png)
    `

```
   func fetchMessage(key1:String){
    let mydatabase = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("message")
    let query = mydatabase.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: key1)
        query.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            for dict in snapshot.children{
                let childsnap = dict as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dict2 = childsnap.value as! [String: Any]
                var message = chatmssage()
                let body = dict2["MesageBody"]! as? String
                let email = dict2["from"]! as? String
                message.body = body
                message.email = email
                self.chatmessagearr.append(message)
                self.mytableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mytableview.delegate = self
    mytableview.dataSource = self
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    messageTXTF.delegate = self
    mytableview.separatorStyle = .none
    let curID = (user!["id"] as? String)!
    let toID = self.reciever.uid!
    key = (curID < toID ? curID+toID : toID+curID )
    fetchMessage(key1:key!)
}
```

Comment: instead of adding images, you should add your code as text.

Comment: @chirag90  ... it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You should call self.myTableView.reloadData() from the main thread after your fetch completes. Like this,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: excuse me sir i added the thread at the end of retrieve func
but the same problem